# AJAX UTF-8 Content Displayed Correctly on ISO-8859 Encoded Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, encoding

So I have a web page that is encoded in ISO-8859 as per the HTTP header that returns its content. I return text content  and as expected it is mangled by the ISO encoding.

However when I make a JSONP AJAX call that returns the same text content , and insert it onto the page, those emoticons are displayed correctly! Notably the AJAX call lacks an encoding type header as its Content-Type header is simply text/javascript.

What's going on here? Does my Chrome browser do some sort of clever tricks to make sure the AJAXed content is displayed correctly?

In case it matters I am using the jQuery library to do AJAX calls.

Comment: It may be because by default jQuery Ajax has content type charset set to UTF-8...contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8') from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @VipinDubey What does the request header have to do with any of this?

Comment: browsers generally use UTF-8 when no charset is defined in a page, since in your case you already have ISO-8859 you may also want to check if the file is saved in same format or not, open file in notepad and go to file save as and see if it has ISO-8859 or UTF-8 file format. While jquery Ajax will continue sending the response in UTF-8 until you define it explicitly..

Comment: @VipinDubey I agree that the AJAX request comes back and by default is treated as UTF-8 encoded content, but how does that explain that content being displayed properly on the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly conjecture, as I haven't looked into it extensively, but from what I understand is that browsers convert HTML textual content to some internal representation (perhaps UTF-16, I don't know). I found a mention of that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Localizations_and_character_encodings#Details_and_browser_internals).

They do that using the clues that the server (`Content-Type` header), the HTML itself (`<meta charset=...`, etc) or the user (by explicitly setting the encoding for a page) provides.

Any *new* textual content that gets pushed into the DOM, for instance that which is retrieved using an AJAX request, undergoes the same transcoding. In other words, the browser doesn't use the encoding of the rest of the page (or perhaps only in the case where it has absolutely no idea when the encoding is), but the encoding that's provided by the server, in the AJAX response (or it uses a default if the server doesn't set it).

So internally, everything gets converted to the same encoding, which is why you can inject UTF-8-encoded data using JS into an ISO-8859-encoded page and it works.

Comment: Could you provide a quote that you think supports your argument. I read a couple of sections of the Mozilla document linked and I did not see any indication that it it using UTF-8 as the default.

Comment: @thatidiotguy JSON's default encoding is UTF-8 ([RFC4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)), is that what you mean? I added the link to show that browsers apparently convert text to an internal representation (but I have no idea what that's based on).

Comment: No, I guess what I mean is that I don't see anything concrete in that link that would suggest that this internal representation is UTF-8. Do you think that the browser is actually displaying different parts of the DOM with a different encoding?

Comment: @thatidiotguy I'm not suggesting that the internal representation is UTF-8 (it's most likely _not_), but textual content from different sources (HTML, AJAX response data, etc) is converted _to_ that internal representation, by using the hints provided by those sources. In your case, the HTML is converted from ISO-8859-1 to _internal_, the JSONP data is converted from UTF-8 to _internal_, etc.

Comment: But the browser could be storing everything in its unicode representation no?

Comment: My guess would be that it's internally represented using UTF-16, but I guess that each browser could be using something different. It's only used internally, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Alright well thanks for the comment. I'll leave this question unanswered as of now in case somebody posts something a little more concrete but this would definitely explain the behavior I'm seeing.